# Appending keys to Nested Dictionary Vba

Tags: vba, dictionary, nested, append

I am working with Nested dictionaries to read the files and to store the data. I have 3 levels in the nested dictionary. Each time I read a file, I want to update the third sub dictionary. Do we have an option in Excel Vba. 
Python has an option [appending-to-a-nested-dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479074/appending-to-a-nested-dictionary) but I really need it in excel vba. I shall be thankful if I get a useful tip.

I followed the two approach

```
Dict3.Add Key3, item3 
Dict2.Add Key2, Dict3
Dict1.add key1, Dict2
```

The problem with this approach is that I cannot add additional keys ex.Key4 to Dict3. Another approach below

```
Dict1(Key1).Dict2(Key2).Dict3.Add Key4, item4
```

is resulting in Runtime error 424. Please suggest me how I can improve the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help or confuse you even more. :)

You just need to refer to the dictionary keys e.g. `Dict1(Key1)(Key2).Add Key4, item4`

That would be the same as `Dict1.Item(Key1).Item(Key2).Add Key4, item4` since `Item` is the default member.

```
Sub T()

    Dim m1 As Scripting.Dictionary, m2 As Scripting.Dictionary, m3 As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant

    Set m1 = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set m2 = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set m3 = New Scripting.Dictionary

    m3.Add "Three", "A" 'add A
    m2.Add "Two", m3
    m1.Add "One", m2

    m1("One")("Two").Add "Four", "B" 'add B
    m1("One")("Two").Add "Five", "C" 'add C

    For Each v1 In m1.Keys
        For Each v2 In m1(v1).Keys
            For Each v3 In m1(v1)(v2).Keys
                Debug.Print m1(v1)(v2)(v3)
            Next v3
        Next v2
    Next v1
End Sub

'A
'B
'C
```

Comment: @Raghu Consider a custom dictionary wrapper class - it will be much easier to read and maintain.